# "No Interface Expected Here" on an abstract class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract class called shape which will be extended by several sub-classes such as 'circle', 'square' etc. I have defined shape as an abstract class but when trying to extend it I get the error "no interface expected here"

```
public abstract class Shape{
   
   protected int x;
   protected int y;
   protected int width;
   protected int height;
   protected Color colour;
   protected int moveX;
   protected int moveY;
   
   public Shape() {
      
   }
   
   public int randomRange(int lo, int hi) {
      
   }
   
   abstract void display(Graphics g);
   
   public void move() {      
      
   }
   
}
```

With code for all of those methods to perform some basic functions which I didn't include for brevities sake. Then my code for the sub-class is:

```
public class Circle extends Shape{
   
   public Circle() {
       super(x,y,width,height,colour);
   }
   
   public void display(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(colour);
      g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
   }
}
```

They are both in the same package which I've named shapePackage.

Comment: What are your includes for `public class Circle`?

Comment: @TravisF I'm sorry I don't understand the question. Do you mean what am I adding to that class?  Because the reason for the abstract is so that I can write up more classes (square, octogon etc) with their own display method

Comment: sorry mate, I meant imports, the only reason I ask is because `java.awt` also has an implementation of `Shape` so if you are importing that instead of your own class it will confuse it.

Comment: the constructor you call from circle doesn't exist in your Shape class. Next to that, your abstract class won't compile, since you have a non-abstract method that should return an int, but doesn't return anything

Comment: @TravisF I am importing java.awt although I tried changing the names of the classes to see if this fixed it and that didn't work

Comment: @Stultuske I just didn't include the code from the methods as I assumed it wasn't relevant to the issue

Comment: This part is your problem `extends Shape` your code probably thinks it is looking at `java.awt.Shape`, but you need it to point to your other custom class, you can do this by either renaming classes or removing the awt imports `import java.awt.Shape;` or `import java.awt.*;` from your class. Otherwise you can call the full path/name of your class `yourPackage.Shape` like so `public class Circle extends yourPackage.Shape{` I don't know the structure of your project, but replace `yourPackage` with the actual package name.

Comment: @sorifiend This fixed it, it was an issue to do with the package, sweet thank you so much

Comment: @MaestroSpook "it wasn't relevant". showing us something that couldn't possible work, and then asking us why it doesn't work. That is kind of relevant. For instance, you not having that constructor, is a dead ringer that you're calling the constructor of a different class. if you feel the actual code doesn't matter in that method, just add something like return 0; so at least we know the problem isn't that your code doesn't compile